# Why do I keep getting short duration schengen visas?

Tags: schengen, france, spain, austria, visa-expiration

Ive never been refused any schengen visas I applied for but I keep getting very short Visas validities. 
The first Schengen Visa I got was 4 days visa from France and the 2nd one was 3 weeks from Spain. 
I wasn’t too worried as I was a student with not a lot of money in my account but I’ve just received my 3rd Schengen Visa from Austria and it’s only valid for 3 weeks again.

I’m Nigerian and have been a UK resident for over 8 years and I’ve also got valid visas to other countries like USA. I travel quite a lot with numerous other visas in my passport, so i think it’s safe for them to assume I keep to visa rules? 
Im full time employed with a cohabiting British partner, and i don’t think I present a risk of being an illegal immigrant (the reason for some countries being strict). 
So I’m just curious as to why I’m consistently given low tenure schengen visas.

Its just frustrating that every time my partner and I have to travel I have to spend a lot of money and time on applying for the visas (this application alone cost £350 in visa fees, compulsory and unnessary winter sports insurance which j don’t partake in, and lost earnings on the application day)

I know other people of same nationality that got 6 month visas the first time they applied even though they haven’t lived in UK long and haven’t travelled much.

It’s such poor value for money for me and wondered if anyone knew  why or how they come to such decisions? 
Will it ever improve?

Comment: As you have a cohabiting British partner, you should be eligible to travel with your partner under the freedom of movement regime, which should at least save you from having to pay visa fees, at least until March.

Comment: Nobody can tell you exactly why they do that. You just might be unlucky. That said when I was a visa National I also used to visit Schengen countries quite a bit and the maximum I ever got was a month, sometimes as little as four days (courtesy of the Germans) . My nationality is Ghanaian and I also live in the USA so quite similar profile to yours.

Comment: Schengen rules are a mess when it comes to visa duration. Much more paranoid countries like Canada or the US routinely issue 10 year visas to all travellers, while Schengen countries have easier application rules, but annoy travellers by requiring them to waste their time before each trip.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/97831/why-dont-countries-always-issue-multi-year-multi-entry-visas

Comment: You've lived in the UK eight years? Apply for ILR and then British citizenship.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately nobody can tell you exactly why they do that. You just might be unlucky.

Before I acquired American citizenship I also used to visit Schengen countries quite a extensively and the maximum I ever got was a month, sometimes as little as four days (courtesy of the Germans). My original nationality is Ghanaian and I also live in the USA so quite similar profile to yours.

Doesn’t make sense to me that a foreign legal UK resident (or in my case USA resident) will abscond to become illegal in the Schengen zone but it is what it is, obviously they have some doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer? You are african (lets not lie about it) We africains they dont trust us. And also whenever u ask for a visa u pay money and visas is a money printing machine for all the EU. So .. yeah hope u get an actual citizenship and all these visa applications will be like just bad memories...
PS : Im a fellow Tunisian citizen and I asked for shengen visa for more than 10 times and I always get 3 months and I live in Canada.